# How to modify existing genetic algorithm to optimize number of hidden layers and hidden layer neurons of an neural network?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I implemented a matlab code that uses genetic algorithm to optimize the weights and biases of a neural network.The complete code is given below:

```
function [population, fitness_score, progress] = run_ann_withGA()

% set RNG seed number to get reproducible results; 
% change seed number to get different results
rng('default');
rng(2);

% load dataset
data = dlmread('spambase.csv'); % example dataset

X = data(:, 1:end-1); % assuming all columns are attributes
Y = data(:, end); % except for the last column for labels

% what to optimize? the neural network weights
% how many values to optimize?
% again, make sure the network's input and output matches the dataset
net = create_network();
num_genes = sum(net.num_parameters);

% set parameters for GA
population_size = 100; % 50 chromosomes for population
generations_max = 1000; % run for 50 generations
selrate = 0.5; % SelectionRate
mutrate = 0.5; % MutationRate
progress = [];

convergence_maxcount = 10; % stop the GA if the average fitness score stopped increasing for 5 generations
convergence_count = 0;
convergence_avg = 0;

% initialize population
population = rand(population_size, num_genes) * 2 - 1;
fitness_score = zeros(population_size, 1);

generations_current = 1;
while generations_current < generations_max
    % test all chromosomes that haven't been tested
    for i = 1:population_size
        if fitness_score(i,1) == 0
            % fitness testing a chromosome
            fitness_score(i,1) = fitness_function(population(i, 1:end), X, Y);
        end
    end

    % find out statistics of the population
    fit_avg = mean(fitness_score);
    fit_max = max(fitness_score);
    progress = [progress; fit_avg, fit_max];

    % convergence? 
    if fit_avg > convergence_avg
        convergence_avg = fit_avg;
        convergence_count = 0;
        disp("Generation " + string(generations_current) + "; AvgFit " + string(fit_avg) + "; BestFit " + string(fit_max));
    else
        convergence_count = convergence_count + 1;
    end

    generations_current = generations_current + 1;
    % stop the GA if reach 100% accuracy or reach convergence?
    % instead of stopping immediately, slowly adjust SelRate and MutRate
    if (fit_max >= 1)
        generations_max = 0;
        disp("Reached convergence.")
        disp("Generation " + string(generations_current) + "; AvgFit " + string(fit_avg) + "; BestFit " + string(fit_max));
    
    elseif (convergence_count > convergence_maxcount)
        % what to do if fitness haven't improved?
        % stop the GA?
      %  generations_max = 0;
      %  disp("Reached convergence.")
     %   disp("Generation " + string(generations_current) + "; AvgFit " + string(fit_avg) + "; BestFit " + string(fit_max));

        % % or adjust selection rate and mutation rate for fine-grained search
         if (selrate < 0.9)
             convergence_count = 0;
             selrate = selrate + 0.1;
             mutrate = mutrate - 0.1;
         else
             generations_max = 0;
             disp("Reached convergence.")
         end
    end

    % do genetic operators
    [population, fitness_score] = genetic_operators(population, fitness_score, selrate, mutrate);
    
end

end



function score = fitness_function(chromosome, X, Y)

net = create_network();
layers = (length(fieldnames(net))-2) / 2; %calculate number of layers %
% set the weights based on the chromosome
for i = 1:layers
    layer_name = 'W' + string(i);
    bias_name = 'b' + string(i);
    
    num_genes = size(net.(layer_name), 1)*size(net.(layer_name), 2); 
    new_layer = reshape(chromosome(1:num_genes), [size(net.(layer_name), 1), size(net.(layer_name), 2)]);
    net.(layer_name) = new_layer;
    chromosome = chromosome(num_genes+1:end);

    num_genes = size(net.(bias_name), 1);
    new_bias = chromosome(1:num_genes);
    net.(bias_name) = new_bias';
    chromosome = chromosome(num_genes+1:end);
end

% now test the new network
Y_pred = test(net, X);

% fitness score is the accuracy of the prediction
% what other fitness score can be calculated?
score = mean(Y == Y_pred');

end


function [population, fitness_score] = genetic_operators(population, fitness_score, selrate, mutrate)

% how many chromosomes to reject?
popsize = size(population, 1);
num_reject = round((1-selrate) * popsize);

for i = 1:num_reject
    % find lowest fitness score and remove the chromosome
    [~, lowest] = min(fitness_score);
    population(lowest, :) = [];
    fitness_score(lowest) = [];
end

% for each rejection, create a new chromosome
num_parents = size(population, 1);
for i = 1:num_reject
    % how to select parent chromosomes?
    % random permutation method
    order = randperm(num_parents);
    parent1 = population(order(1), :);
    parent2 = population(order(2), :);

    % mix-and-match
    offspring = (parent1 + parent2) / 2;

    % mutation
    mut_val = rand(1, size(population(1,:), 2));
    mut_val = mut_val * mutrate; 

    for j = 1:size(mut_val, 2)
        if rand < mutrate
            offspring(1, j) = offspring(1, j) + mut_val(1, j);
        end
    end
    
    % add new offspring to population
    population = [population; offspring];
    fitness_score = [fitness_score; 0];
end
```

The function for creating the neural network is given below:

```
function net = create_network(input_layer_units,hidden_layers,hidden_layer_units,output_layer_units)
% example values of each variable

%input_layer_units = 57; % how many input features?
%hidden_layers = 2; % how many hidden layers?
%hidden_layer_units = [100,100]; % how many nodes per hidden layer? 100 for
%first hidden layer and 100 for second neural network
%output_layer_units = 2; % how many outputs?

% create the network
net = struct();
net.hidden_layers = hidden_layers;
number_of_parameters = [];

% input layer
layer_name = 'W1'; 
bias_name = 'b1';
layer = rand(hidden_layer_units(1), input_layer_units)*2 - 1; % "*2 - 1" sets value range to [-1, +1]
bias = rand(hidden_layer_units(1), 1)*2 - 1;
net.(layer_name) = layer;
net.(bias_name) = bias;

number_of_parameters = [number_of_parameters; size(layer, 1)*size(layer, 2); size(bias, 1)]; % one set for hidden layer, another set for bias

% create hidden layers and output layer
for i = 1:hidden_layers
    layer_name = 'W' + string(i+1);
    bias_name = 'b' + string(i+1);

    if i == hidden_layers
        layer = rand(output_layer_units, hidden_layer_units(i))*2 - 1;
        bias = rand(output_layer_units, 1)*2 - 1;
    else
        layer = rand(hidden_layer_units(i+1), hidden_layer_units(i))*2 - 1;
        bias = rand(hidden_layer_units(i+1), 1)*2 - 1;
    end
    number_of_parameters = [number_of_parameters; size(layer, 1)*size(layer, 2); size(bias, 1)];

    net.(layer_name) = layer;
    net.(bias_name) = bias;
end

net.num_parameters = number_of_parameters;

end
    end
```

As you can see the genetic algorithm `run_ann_withGA` can currently only optimize the weights and biases of a neural network.I want to modify the GA to also optimize `hidden_layers`
and `hidden_layer_units`. For example I can set the maximum number of hidden layers to be 10 and the maximum number of neurons in each hidden layer is 20.I want the genetic algorithm to not only find the best possible weights and biases but also the best number of hidden layers (between 1 to the 10) and the best number of neurons in each hidden layer (between 1 to 20). I am not sure how to do this as I was thinking of using multiple for loops (for each number of hidden layers and hidden layer neurons) but I guess that is not the most efficient way.

Comment: what's in spambase.csv? would you please supply this file or part of it so that readers can reproduce the question in same terms?

Comment: Yeah sure.Here is the link to the  file:https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/spambase
Currently the network can handle any data as long you set the correct number of input layer and output layer units.It can currently optimize the weights and biases of a specific  architecture given to the algorithm.But I also want it to find the ideal number of hidden layers and hidden layer units in each layer as well